# Angular inject.get service with parameter in constructor how to pass value

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, code-injection

I tried this way of injecting service in angular but when I tried call LogService in GlobalErrorHandler, kindly see code below. It doesn't work.

What I found out is that I didn't pass any userId which is in the constructor of LogService. When I tried to remove the userId in the constructor it works, but the other way isn't, it doesn't continue.

I am new to angular, do you have any idea how can I pass the userId while calling the LogService in GlobalErrorHandler?

Any help or suggestion is much appreciated. Thanks!

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class LogService {
  private logger!: Logger;

  constructor(private userId: string) {}
}
```

other file call LogService

```
export class GlobalErrorHandler extends ErrorHandler {›
  constructor(private injector: Injector) {
    super();
  }

  public handleError(error: any | HttpError | HttpErrorResponse ) {
    const logService: LogService = this.injector.get(LogService); // error occur here it does stop here :(
    const router: Router = this.injector.get(Router);

    const message = error.message ? error.message : error.toString();
    if (error.status) {
      error = new Error(message);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I rarely use `injector: Injector`, so I can not help you with this syntax.

So another solution you can try is that :

1. Create a `GlobalErrorHandlerService` like your `LogService`.
2. Inside `GlobalErrorHandlerService` constructor declare `private logService : LogService` .
3. In your LogService file, create a method in order to set the user id like `setUserId(userId:string)...`.
4. Inside `GlobalErrorHandlerService` constructor, call `this.logService.setUserId(userId)`